# Windows - Named pipes performance recommendations with C#

Tags: .net, windows, performance, named-pipes

I am currently evaluating named pipes for IPC on Windows with .NET/C#.
I am currently looking at a single producer, single consumer scenario.
Are there any good performance consideration guidelines?
In my first test case I was comparing the speed of large messages vs small messages and seems to be that large (64k) messages are sent as quick as small (48 Bytes) packages. This was with the default parameters. I might add more test scenarios, but this is quite time-consuming and thus I am looking for guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

We used Named Pipes on Windows NT 4 and Windows 2000. Really fast.

When we switched to XP, occasionally it would be fast, the rest of the time slow. With exactly the same code.

We wrote our own shared memory data transport. Seriously fast.